# how can i find tomorrow and yesterday with teelrik kendo DatePicker or angularjs ?

Tags: angularjs, telerik-mvc

I'am  working on angularjs and i want to display today,tomorrow and yesterday .is there any demo in angularjs or  teelrik kendo DatePicker to do that ?

thanks
best regards

Comment: Have you checked this [link](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/angular).

Comment: yes but i want to show tomorrow and yesterday buttons inside the date picker like today button

Comment: Please refer [this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/template). Basically you need to customize 'footer' property while initializing the datepicker. I hope this gives you some idea.

Comment: ok,but how can i get the date of yesterday or tomorrow?footer: "Today - #=kendo.toString(data, 'd') #",